# Why do I get the error Call to a member function read() on a non-object?

Tags: php, forum

Why do I get the following error [here](http://projectstratos.com/forum) when trying to intergrate my site with myBB?:

`Fatal error: Call to a member function read() on a non-object in /hermes/bosweb/web035/b357/ipg.projectstratoscom/forum/global.php on line 24`

here is the full global.php file:

```
<?php
/**
 * MyBB 1.6
 * Copyright 2010 MyBB Group, All Rights Reserved
 *
 * Website: http://mybb.com
 * License: http://mybb.com/about/license
 *
 * $Id: global.php 5016 2010-06-12 00:24:02Z RyanGordon $
 */

$working_dir = dirname(__FILE__);
if(!$working_dir)
{
    $working_dir = '/forum/';
}

// Load main MyBB core file which begins all of the magic
require_once $working_dir."/inc/init.php";

$shutdown_queries = array();

// Read the usergroups cache as well as the moderators cache
$groupscache = $cache->read("usergroups");

// If the groups cache doesn't exist, update it and re-read it
if(!is_array($groupscache))
{
    $cache->update_usergroups();
    $groupscache = $cache->read("usergroups");
}

if(!defined('THIS_SCRIPT'))
{
    define('THIS_SCRIPT', '');
}

$current_page = my_strtolower(basename(THIS_SCRIPT));

// Send page headers - don't send no-cache headers for attachment.php
if($current_page != "attachment.php")
{
    send_page_headers();
}

// Do not use session system for defined pages
if((@isset($mybb->input['action']) && @isset($nosession[$mybb->input['action']])) || (@isset($mybb->input['thumbnail']) && $current_page == 'attachment.php'))
{
    define("NO_ONLINE", 1);
}

// Create session for this user
require_once MYBB_ROOT."inc/class_session.php";
$session = new session;
$session->init();
$mybb->session = &$session;

$mybb->user['ismoderator'] = is_moderator("", "", $mybb->user['uid']);

// Set our POST validation code here
$mybb->post_code = generate_post_check();

// Set and load the language
if($mybb->input['language'] && $lang->language_exists($mybb->input['language']))
{
    $mybb->settings['bblanguage'] = $mybb->input['language'];
    // If user is logged in, update their language selection with the new one
    if($mybb->user['uid'])
    {
        $db->update_query("users", array("language" => $db->escape_string($mybb->settings['bblanguage'])), "uid='{$mybb->user['uid']}'");
    }
    // Guest = cookie
    else
    {
        my_setcookie("mybblang", $mybb->settings['bblanguage']);
    }
    $mybb->user['language'] = $mybb->settings['bblanguage'];
}
// Cookied language!
else if($mybb->cookies['mybblang'] && $lang->language_exists($mybb->cookies['mybblang']))
{
    $mybb->settings['bblanguage'] = $mybb->cookies['mybblang'];
}
else if(!isset($mybb->settings['bblanguage']))
{
    $mybb->settings['bblanguage'] = "english";
}

// Load language
$lang->set_language($mybb->settings['bblanguage']);
$lang->load("global");
$lang->load("messages");

// Run global_start plugin hook now that the basics are set up
$plugins->run_hooks("global_start");

if(function_exists('mb_internal_encoding') && !empty($lang->settings['charset']))
{
    @mb_internal_encoding($lang->settings['charset']);
}

// Select the board theme to use.
$loadstyle = '';
$load_from_forum = 0;
$style = array();

// This user has a custom theme set in their profile
if(isset($mybb->user['style']) && intval($mybb->user['style']) != 0)
{
    $loadstyle = "tid='".$mybb->user['style']."'";
}

$valid = array(
    "showthread.php", 
    "forumdisplay.php",
    "newthread.php",
    "newreply.php",
    "ratethread.php",
    "editpost.php",
    "polls.php",
    "sendthread.php",
    "printthread.php",
    "moderation.php"
);

if(in_array($current_page, $valid))
{
    // If we're accessing a post, fetch the forum theme for it and if we're overriding it
    if($mybb->input['pid'])
    {
        $query = $db->query("
            SELECT f.style, f.overridestyle, p.*
            FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."forums f
            LEFT JOIN ".TABLE_PREFIX."posts p ON(f.fid=p.fid)
            WHERE p.pid='".intval($mybb->input['pid'])."'
            LIMIT 1
        ");
        $style = $db->fetch_array($query);

        $load_from_forum = 1;
    }

    // We have a thread id and a forum id, we can easily fetch the theme for this forum
    else if($mybb->input['tid'])
    {
        $query = $db->query("
            SELECT f.style, f.overridestyle, t.*
            FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."forums f
            LEFT JOIN ".TABLE_PREFIX."threads t ON (f.fid=t.fid)
            WHERE t.tid='".intval($mybb->input['tid'])."'
            LIMIT 1
        ");
        $style = $db->fetch_array($query);
        $load_from_forum = 1;
    }

    // We have a forum id - simply load the theme from it
    else if($mybb->input['fid'])
    {
        cache_forums();
        $style = $forum_cache[intval($mybb->input['fid'])];
        $load_from_forum = 1;
    }
}
unset($valid);

// From all of the above, a theme was found
if(isset($style['style']) && $style['style'] > 0)
{
    // This theme is forced upon the user, overriding their selection
    if($style['overridestyle'] == 1 || !isset($mybb->user['style']))
    {
        $loadstyle = "tid='".intval($style['style'])."'";
    }
}

// After all of that no theme? Load the board default
if(empty($loadstyle))
{
    $loadstyle = "def='1'";
}

// Fetch the theme to load from the database
$query = $db->simple_select("themes", "name, tid, properties, stylesheets", $loadstyle, array('limit' => 1));
$theme = $db->fetch_array($query);

// No theme was found - we attempt to load the master or any other theme
if(!$theme['tid'])
{
    // Missing theme was from a forum, run a query to set any forums using the theme to the default
    if($load_from_forum == 1)
    {
        $db->update_query("forums", array("style" => 0), "style='{$style['style']}'");
    }
    // Missing theme was from a user, run a query to set any users using the theme to the default
    else if($load_from_user == 1)
    {
        $db->update_query("users", array("style" => 0), "style='{$style['style']}'");
    }
    // Attempt to load the master or any other theme if the master is not available
    $query = $db->simple_select("themes", "name, tid, properties, stylesheets", "", array("order_by" => "tid", "limit" => 1));
    $theme = $db->fetch_array($query);
}
$theme = @array_merge($theme, unserialize($theme['properties']));

// Fetch all necessary stylesheets
$theme['stylesheets'] = unserialize($theme['stylesheets']);
$stylesheet_scripts = array("global", basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));
foreach($stylesheet_scripts as $stylesheet_script)
{
    $stylesheet_actions = array("global");
    if($mybb->input['action'])
    {
        $stylesheet_actions[] = $mybb->input['action'];
    }
    // Load stylesheets for global actions and the current action
    foreach($stylesheet_actions as $stylesheet_action)
    {
        if(!$stylesheet_action)
        {
            continue;
        }

        if($theme['stylesheets'][$stylesheet_script][$stylesheet_action])
        {
            // Actually add the stylesheets to the list
            foreach($theme['stylesheets'][$stylesheet_script][$stylesheet_action] as $page_stylesheet)
            {
                if($already_loaded[$page_stylesheet])
                {
                    continue;
                }
                $stylesheets .= "<link type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"{$mybb->settings['bburl']}/{$page_stylesheet}\" />\n";
                $already_loaded[$page_stylesheet] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}

// Are we linking to a remote theme server?
if(substr($theme['imgdir'], 0, 7) == "http://")
{
    // If a language directory for the current language exists within the theme - we use it
    if(!empty($mybb->user['language']))
    {
        $theme['imglangdir'] = $theme['imgdir'].'/'.$mybb->user['language'];
    }
    else
    {
        // Check if a custom language directory exists for this theme
        if(!empty($mybb->settings['bblanguage']))
        {
            $theme['imglangdir'] = $theme['imgdir'].'/'.$mybb->settings['bblanguage'];
        }
        // Otherwise, the image language directory is the same as the language directory for the theme
        else
        {
            $theme['imglangdir'] = $theme['imgdir'];
        }
    }
}
else
{
    if(!@is_dir($theme['imgdir']))
    {
        $theme['imgdir'] = "images";
    }

    // If a language directory for the current language exists within the theme - we use it
    if(!empty($mybb->user['language']) && is_dir($theme['imgdir'].'/'.$mybb->user['language']))
    {
        $theme['imglangdir'] = $theme['imgdir'].'/'.$mybb->user['language'];
    }
    else
    {
        // Check if a custom language directory exists for this theme
        if(is_dir($theme['imgdir'].'/'.$mybb->settings['bblanguage']))
        {
            $theme['imglangdir'] = $theme['imgdir'].'/'.$mybb->settings['bblanguage'];
        }
        // Otherwise, the image language directory is the same as the language directory for the theme
        else
        {
            $theme['imglangdir'] = $theme['imgdir'];
        }
    }
}

// Theme logo - is it a relative URL to the forum root? Append bburl
if(!preg_match("#^(\.\.?(/|$)|([a-z0-9]+)://)#i", $theme['logo']) && substr($theme['logo'], 0, 1) != "/")
{
    $theme['logo'] = $mybb->settings['bburl']."/".$theme['logo'];
}

// Load Main Templates and Cached Templates
if(isset($templatelist))
{
    $templatelist .= ',';
}
$templatelist .= "css,headerinclude,header,footer,gobutton,htmldoctype,header_welcomeblock_member,header_welcomeblock_guest,header_welcomeblock_member_admin,global_pm_alert,global_unreadreports,";
$templatelist .= ",global_pending_joinrequests,nav,nav_sep,nav_bit,nav_sep_active,nav_bit_active,footer_languageselect,header_welcomeblock_member_moderator,redirect,error";
$templates->cache($db->escape_string($templatelist));

// Set the current date and time now
$datenow = my_date($mybb->settings['dateformat'], TIME_NOW, '', false);
$timenow = my_date($mybb->settings['timeformat'], TIME_NOW);
$lang->welcome_current_time = $lang->sprintf($lang->welcome_current_time, $datenow.', '.$timenow);

// Format the last visit date of this user appropriately
if(isset($mybb->user['lastvisit']))
{
    $lastvisit = my_date($mybb->settings['dateformat'], $mybb->user['lastvisit']) . ', ' . my_date($mybb->settings['timeformat'], $mybb->user['lastvisit']);
}

// Otherwise, they've never visited before
else
{
    $lastvisit = $lang->lastvisit_never;
}

// If the board is closed and we have an Administrator, show board closed warning
$bbclosedwarning = '';
if($mybb->settings['boardclosed'] == 1 && $mybb->usergroup['cancp'] == 1)
{
    eval("\$bbclosedwarning = \"".$templates->get("global_boardclosed_warning")."\";");
}

// Prepare the main templates for use
unset($admincplink);

// Load appropriate welcome block for the current logged in user
if($mybb->user['uid'] != 0)
{
    // User can access the admin cp and we're not hiding admin cp links, fetch it
    if($mybb->usergroup['cancp'] == 1 && $mybb->config['hide_admin_links'] != 1)
    {
        eval("\$admincplink = \"".$templates->get("header_welcomeblock_member_admin")."\";");
    }

    if($mybb->usergroup['canmodcp'] == 1)
    {
        eval("\$modcplink = \"".$templates->get("header_welcomeblock_member_moderator")."\";");
    }

    // Format the welcome back message
    $lang->welcome_back = $lang->sprintf($lang->welcome_back, $mybb->user['username'], $lastvisit);

    // Tell the user their PM usage
    $lang->welcome_pms_usage = $lang->sprintf($lang->welcome_pms_usage, my_number_format($mybb->user['pms_unread']), my_number_format($mybb->user['pms_total']));
    eval("\$welcomeblock = \"".$templates->get("header_welcomeblock_member")."\";");
}
// Otherwise, we have a guest
else
{
    eval("\$welcomeblock = \"".$templates->get("header_welcomeblock_guest")."\";");
}

$pending_joinrequests = '';

// Read the group leaders cache
$groupleaders = $cache->read("groupleaders");
if($mybb->user['uid'] != 0 && is_array($groupleaders) && array_key_exists($mybb->user['uid'], $groupleaders))
{
    $groupleader = $groupleaders[$mybb->user['uid']];

    $gids = "";
    foreach($groupleader as $user)
    {
        if($user['canmanagerequests'] != 1)
        {
            continue;
        }

        $gids .= ",{$user['gid']}";
    }

    $query = $db->simple_select("joinrequests", "COUNT(uid) as total", "gid IN (0{$gids})");
    $total_joinrequests = $db->fetch_field($query, "total");

    $pending_joinrequests = "";
    if($total_joinrequests > 0)
    {
        if($total_joinrequests == 1)
        {
            $lang->pending_joinrequests = $lang->pending_joinrequest;
        }
        else
        {
            $lang->pending_joinrequests = $lang->sprintf($lang->pending_joinrequests, $total_joinrequests);
        }
        eval("\$pending_joinrequests = \"".$templates->get("global_pending_joinrequests")."\";");
    }
}

$unreadreports = '';
// This user is a moderator, super moderator or administrator
if($mybb->usergroup['cancp'] == 1 || $mybb->user['ismoderator'] && $mybb->usergroup['canmodcp'])
{
    // Read the reported posts cache
    $reported = $cache->read("reportedposts");

    // 0 or more reported posts currently exist
    if($reported['unread'] > 0)
    {
        if($reported['unread'] == 1)
        {
            $lang->unread_reports = $lang->unread_report;
        }
        else
        {
            $lang->unread_reports = $lang->sprintf($lang->unread_reports, $reported['unread']);
        }
        eval("\$unreadreports = \"".$templates->get("global_unreadreports")."\";");
    }
}

// Got a character set?
if($lang->settings['charset'])
{
    $charset = $lang->settings['charset'];
}
// If not, revert to UTF-8
else
{
    $charset = "UTF-8";
}

// Is this user apart of a banned group?
$bannedwarning = '';
if($mybb->usergroup['isbannedgroup'] == 1)
{
    // Fetch details on their ban
    $query = $db->simple_select("banned", "*", "uid='{$mybb->user['uid']}'", array('limit' => 1));
    $ban = $db->fetch_array($query);
    if($ban['uid'])
    {
        // Format their ban lift date and reason appropriately
        if($ban['lifted'] > 0)
        {
            $banlift = my_date($mybb->settings['dateformat'], $ban['lifted']) . ", " . my_date($mybb->settings['timeformat'], $ban['lifted']);
        }
        else 
        {
            $banlift = $lang->banned_lifted_never;
        }
        $reason = htmlspecialchars_uni($ban['reason']);
    }
    if(empty($reason))
    {
        $reason = $lang->unknown;
    }
    if(empty($banlift))
    {
        $banlift = $lang->unknown;
    }
    // Display a nice warning to the user
    eval("\$bannedwarning = \"".$templates->get("global_bannedwarning")."\";");
}

$lang->ajax_loading = str_replace("'", "\\'", $lang->ajax_loading);

// Check if this user has a new private message.
if($mybb->user['pmnotice'] == 2 && $mybb->user['pms_unread'] > 0 && $mybb->settings['enablepms'] != 0 && $mybb->usergroup['canusepms'] != 0 && $mybb->usergroup['canview'] != 0 && ($current_page != "private.php" || $mybb->input['action'] != "read"))
{
    $query = $db->query("
        SELECT pm.subject, pm.pmid, fu.username AS fromusername, fu.uid AS fromuid
        FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."privatemessages pm
        LEFT JOIN ".TABLE_PREFIX."users fu ON (fu.uid=pm.fromid)
        WHERE pm.folder='1' AND pm.uid='{$mybb->user['uid']}' AND pm.status='0'
        ORDER BY pm.dateline DESC
        LIMIT 1
    ");
    $pm = $db->fetch_array($query);

    if($pm['fromuid'] == 0)
    {
        $pm['fromusername'] = $lang->mybb_engine;
        $user_text = $pm['fromusername'];
    }
    else
    {
        $user_text = build_profile_link($pm['fromusername'], $pm['fromuid']);
    }

    if($mybb->user['pms_unread'] == 1)
    {
        $privatemessage_text = $lang->sprintf($lang->newpm_notice_one, $user_text, $pm['pmid'], htmlspecialchars_uni($pm['subject']));
    }
    else
    {
        $privatemessage_text = $lang->sprintf($lang->newpm_notice_multiple, $mybb->user['pms_unread'], $user_text, $pm['pmid'], htmlspecialchars_uni($pm['subject']));
    }
    eval("\$pm_notice = \"".$templates->get("global_pm_alert")."\";");
}

// Set up some of the default templates
eval("\$headerinclude = \"".$templates->get("headerinclude")."\";");
eval("\$gobutton = \"".$templates->get("gobutton")."\";");
eval("\$htmldoctype = \"".$templates->get("htmldoctype", 1, 0)."\";");
eval("\$header = \"".$templates->get("header")."\";");

$copy_year = my_date("Y", TIME_NOW);

// Are we showing version numbers in the footer?
if($mybb->settings['showvernum'] == 1)
{
    $mybbversion = ' '.$mybb->version;
}
else
{
    $mybbversion = '';
}

// Check to see if we have any tasks to run
$task_cache = $cache->read("tasks");
if(!$task_cache['nextrun'])
{
    $task_cache['nextrun'] = TIME_NOW;
}
if($task_cache['nextrun'] <= TIME_NOW)
{
    $task_image = "<img src=\"{$mybb->settings['bburl']}/task.php\" border=\"0\" width=\"1\" height=\"1\" alt=\"\" />";
}
else
{
    $task_image = '';
}

// Are we showing the quick language selection box?
$lang_select = '';
if($mybb->settings['showlanguageselect'] != 0)
{
    $languages = $lang->get_languages();
    foreach($languages as $key => $language)
    {
        $language = htmlspecialchars_uni($language);
        // Current language matches
        if($lang->language == $key)
        {
            $lang_options .= "<option value=\"{$key}\" selected=\"selected\">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{$language}</option>\n";
        }
        else
        {
            $lang_options .= "<option value=\"{$key}\">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{$language}</option>\n";
        }
    }

    $lang_redirect_url = get_current_location(true, 'language');

    eval("\$lang_select = \"".$templates->get("footer_languageselect")."\";");
}

// DST Auto detection enabled?
if($mybb->user['uid'] > 0 && $mybb->user['dstcorrection'] == 2)
{
    $auto_dst_detection = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">if(MyBB) { Event.observe(window, 'load', function() { MyBB.detectDSTChange('".($mybb->user['timezone']+$mybb->user['dst'])."'); }); }</script>\n";
}

eval("\$footer = \"".$templates->get("footer")."\";");

// Add our main parts to the navigation
$navbits = array();
$navbits[0]['name'] = $mybb->settings['bbname_orig'];
$navbits[0]['url'] = $mybb->settings['bburl']."/index.php";

// Set the link to the archive.
$archive_url = $mybb->settings['bburl']."/archive/index.php";

// Check banned ip addresses
if(is_banned_ip($session->ipaddress, true))
{
    if ($mybb->user['uid'])
    {
        $db->delete_query("sessions", "ip='".$db->escape_string($session->ipaddress)."' OR uid='{$mybb->user['uid']}'");
    }
    else
    {
        $db->delete_query("sessions", "ip='".$db->escape_string($session->ipaddress)."'");
    }
    error($lang->error_banned);
}

$closed_bypass = array(
    "member.php" => array(
        "login",
        "do_login",
        "logout",
    ),
    "captcha.php",
);

// If the board is closed, the user is not an administrator and they're not trying to login, show the board closed message
if($mybb->settings['boardclosed'] == 1 && $mybb->usergroup['cancp'] != 1 && !in_array($current_page, $closed_bypass) && (!is_array($closed_bypass[$current_page]) || !in_array($mybb->input['action'], $closed_bypass[$current_page])))
{
    // Show error
    $lang->error_boardclosed .= "<blockquote>{$mybb->settings['boardclosed_reason']}</blockquote>";
    error($lang->error_boardclosed);
    exit;
}

// Load Limiting
if($mybb->usergroup['cancp'] != 1 && $mybb->settings['load'] > 0 && ($load = get_server_load()) && $load != $lang->unknown && $load > $mybb->settings['load'])
{
    // User is not an administrator and the load limit is higher than the limit, show an error
    error($lang->error_loadlimit);
}

// If there is a valid referrer in the URL, cookie it
if(!$mybb->user['uid'] && $mybb->settings['usereferrals'] == 1 && (isset($mybb->input['referrer']) || isset($mybb->input['referrername'])))
{
    if(isset($mybb->input['referrername']))
    {
        $condition = "username='".$db->escape_string($mybb->input['referrername'])."'";
    }
    else
    {
        $condition = "uid='".intval($mybb->input['referrer'])."'";
    }
    $query = $db->simple_select("users", "uid", $condition, array('limit' => 1));
    $referrer = $db->fetch_array($query);
    if($referrer['uid'])
    {
        my_setcookie("mybb[referrer]", $referrer['uid']);
    }
}

if($mybb->usergroup['canview'] != 1)
{
    // Check pages allowable even when not allowed to view board
    if(defined("ALLOWABLE_PAGE"))
    {
        if(is_string(ALLOWABLE_PAGE))
        {
            $allowable_actions = explode(',', ALLOWABLE_PAGE);

            if(!in_array($mybb->input['action'], $allowable_actions))
            {
                error_no_permission();
            }

            unset($allowable_actions);
        }
        else if(ALLOWABLE_PAGE !== 1)
        {
            error_no_permission();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        error_no_permission();
    }
}

// work out which items the user has collapsed
$colcookie = $mybb->cookies['collapsed'];

// set up collapsable items (to automatically show them us expanded)
if($colcookie)
{
    $col = explode("|", $colcookie);
    if(!is_array($col))
    {
        $col[0] = $colcookie; // only one item
    }
    unset($collapsed);
    foreach($col as $key => $val)
    {
        $ex = $val."_e";
        $co = $val."_c";
        $collapsed[$co] = "display: show;";
        $collapsed[$ex] = "display: none;";
        $collapsedimg[$val] = "_collapsed";
    }
}

// Run hooks for end of global.php
$plugins->run_hooks("global_end");

$globaltime = $maintimer->getTime();
?>
```

Comment: Try posting the relevant sections only. Nothing turns people off more than having to dig through some else's code.

Comment: The `$cache` is not an object.

Comment: what does this mean EmCo? and John I didn't think this would be an issue but this it the code on line 24: $groupscache = $cache->read("usergroups");

Comment: @Yesterday: I mean that you may be having a problem with the constructor of `$cache`.

Comment: And how would I be able to fix this, or at least find the problem with it?

Comment: @Yesterday: See stealthyninja answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at the code in inc/init.php, you can see that on line 129 the $cache variable is created. In your case this probably is going wrong. Did you set the correct paths, for example in line 43 of the same file? Use echo and print_r to make sure the variable is set!